# Illustrator to SVG: different shades for different browsers

Tags: firefox, svg, transparency, microsoft-edge, adobe-illustrator

As you can see from the images below, my project created in Adobe Illustrator is corrupt once saved in SVG format:

Project components:
[image]

Finished project / SVG: 
[image]

---

SVG Options:
    SVG Profiles: SVG 1.1
    Options:
        Image Location: Link

I would kindly like to know what I'm doing wrong, if I should combine paths instead of overlapping them, or something else.

### minimal reproducible example

Trying to create a reproducible example I realized that the path in the second layer reacted in a strange way, if you set the gradient slider to 50% or more, in mozilla firefox the gradient will be more relaxed losing #F6EC48 color

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="554.074px" height="237.102px" viewBox="0 0 554.074 237.102" enable-background="new 0 0 554.074 237.102"
     xml:space="preserve">
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="255.4512" y1="97.5811" x2="293.5728" y2="163.6096">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:0.8"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F6EC48;stop-opacity:0"/>
</linearGradient>
<path fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M238.048,152.873
    c18.596,22.147,77.841,13.558,80.465-15.033c2.625-28.591-24.098-54.162-41.876-51.329
    C258.858,89.344,225.774,138.256,238.048,152.873z"/>
</svg>
```

### The problem may be the color not supported on mozilla firefox?

---

### Little Update:

The problem seems to be the inclination of the container of the path, the first one that i posted was inclinated by few grades:
[image][image]
 and it's when the problem occur.Instead, when the container of the path is horizontal:
[image][image]
The problem seems to have disappeared.
Here is the code of the second image:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="554.074px" height="237.102px" viewBox="0 0 554.074 237.102" enable-background="new 0 0 554.074 237.102"
     xml:space="preserve">
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="231.3887" y1="177.9214" x2="315.833" y2="177.9214" gradientTransform="matrix(0.5844 0.8114 -0.8114 0.5844 265.1226 -213.5356)">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:0.8"/>
    <stop  offset="0.0617" style="stop-color:#1D1D16;stop-opacity:0.7507"/>
    <stop  offset="0.1976" style="stop-color:#47452D;stop-opacity:0.6419"/>
    <stop  offset="0.3352" style="stop-color:#6F6B3C;stop-opacity:0.5318"/>
    <stop  offset="0.4719" style="stop-color:#989245;stop-opacity:0.4225"/>
    <stop  offset="0.6073" style="stop-color:#BCB449;stop-opacity:0.3141"/>
    <stop  offset="0.7412" style="stop-color:#D9CF4A;stop-opacity:0.207"/>
    <stop  offset="0.873" style="stop-color:#EDE248;stop-opacity:0.1016"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F6EC48;stop-opacity:0"/>
</linearGradient>
<path fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M235.332,96.394c-7.2,28.412,34.958,72.049,60.028,57.272
    c25.069-14.777,30.271-51.903,17.409-64.846C299.907,75.876,240.083,77.641,235.332,96.394z"/>
</svg>
```

As you can see a gradientTransform appeared with more offset...

### Could someone explain me what is happening?

Comment: I test your code directly in different browsers and it seems there's no difference between the images in different browsers. The results are all the same [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thq5p.png) in different browsers.

Comment: @YuZhou Have you tried with mozilla firefox? i got this into the browser https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYvd3.png

Comment: Yes, also tried with Firefox 71. You could check the result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrKAu.png). Maybe the different browser version causes the issue. You could try to update your Firefox to the latest version and try again.

Comment: @YuZhou I'm not understanding xd [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDvZN.png)